# Protobuf set_foo() fails

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Im struggling with the protobuf setter. Program terminates whenever I try to use it.

```cpp
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
bluetoothDevice.set_name(std::string(name));
```

Also, when i use an allocated setter version with preallocated object, it works.
stacktrace I get.

```
Callstack Information (PID:10157)
Call Stack Count: 22
 0: google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, google::protobuf::Arena*) + 0x83 (0x98adc6c8) [/usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so.25.0.0] + 0x326c8
 1: BluetoothDevice::set_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) + 0x58 (0x98d36a2c) [/opt/usr/globalapps/com.samsung.jrazek.flutter_blue_tizen_example/lib/libflutter_plugins.so] + 0x202a2c
 2: btu::BluetoothManager::notifyDiscoveryResultLE(bt_adapter_le_device_scan_result_info_s const&) + 0x2b8 (0x98d36230) [/opt/usr/globalapps/com.samsung.jrazek.flutter_blue_tizen_example/lib/libflutter_plugins.so] + 0x202230
 3: btu::BluetoothManager::adapterDeviceDiscoveryStateChangedCallbackLE(int, bt_adapter_le_device_scan_result_info_s*, void*) + 0xa8 (0x98d35f40) [/opt/usr/globalapps/com.samsung.jrazek.flutter_blue_tizen_example/lib/libflutter_plugins.so] + 0x201f40
 4: (0x989f6ee9) [/usr/lib/libcapi-network-bluetooth.so.0.6.0] + 0x14ee9
 5: g_variant_lookup_value + 0xbec7 (0x98969ec7) [/usr/lib/libbluetooth-api.so.1.0.0] + 0xbec7
 6: (0x9898fb27) [/usr/lib/libbluetooth-api.so.1.0.0] + 0x31b27
 7: (0xb664ee17) [/usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.6200.3] + 0xb6e17
 8: g_main_context_dispatch + 0xcc (0xb68fdd85) [/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6200.3] + 0x3bd85
 9: (0xb6ee5021) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x17021
10: (0xb6ee6c45) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x18c45
11: (0xb6ee71db) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x191db
12: (0xb6ee775f) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x1975f
13: (0xb6eeaf5f) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x1cf5f
14: efl_loop_begin + 0x50 (0xb6eea40d) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x1c40d
15: ecore_main_loop_begin + 0x4e (0xb6ee64c7) [/usr/lib/libecore.so.1.25.1] + 0x184c7
16: appcore_base_init + 0x186 (0xb5da1817) [/usr/lib/libappcore-common.so.1.15.1] + 0x4817
17: appcore_ui_base_init + 0x164 (0xa43894e1) [/usr/lib/libappcore-ui.so.1.15.1] + 0x34e1
18: appcore_efl_base_init + 0x3c (0xa43c61dd) [/usr/lib/libappcore-efl.so.1.15.1] + 0x21dd
19: (0xa43d9383) [/usr/lib/libcapi-appfw-application.so.0.5.26] + 0x1383
20: ui_app_main + 0x80 (0xa43d9599) [/usr/lib/libcapi-appfw-application.so.0.5.26] + 0x1599
21: (0xa471de91) [/usr/share/dotnet.tizen/framework/Tizen.Applications.UI.ni.dll] + 0x1e91
End of Call Stack
STACK_SHA256: 11fd110e322b45c53225b556f3dbafbabbf86fdcf31d563c133f84393c081a61
```

protobuf class:

```proto
message BluetoothDevice {
  enum Type {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    CLASSIC = 1;
    LE = 2;
    DUAL = 3;
  };

  string remote_id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  Type type = 3;
}
```

what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: I wouldn't rule out that this is a bug in protobuf. Unless you're initializing protobuf itself in some particular way that isn't clear from your question, the two lines you mention should work as-is. Maybe open a ticket with them on GitHub.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED agreed, however, OP is not the first person to use protobuf, and the code seems extremely straightforward - what kind of bug might it be?, so something is up there. My first line of investigation would be corrupt installation. How was protobuf lib installed? Is it shared or static? Are we sure the runtime C/C++ is the same? Are we sure ABI is compatible?

Comment: Library was built with this setup `./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/user/libs --host=arm-linux-gnueabi CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"` It's a shared library. Also worth mentioning is that I use lite version of protobuf. During generating protobuf files i used an `option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;` option

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue was that the protobuf was build with gcc compiler while the program was built with llvm.

Although the ABI was compatible, while passing the `const char*` to the `set_foo` changed the content somehow.

Recompiling the protobuf with llvm fixed the issue.